# Dash in SQL Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert records into my table but keep getting an error due to the dash (Invalid column name 'NJB572'), how can I go about this? I have 2 columns in this table, both VARCHAR.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory VALUES

(131-NJB572, 'BROOM')
(PTI-I20, '9/16 IRONWORKERS')
(PTI-I16, '13/16" PUNCH');
```

Comment: String values must be enclosed in single quotes. You did that for the second value already, why not the first too?

Comment: I'm still learning! However, for a record such as ('PTI-I20-13/16', 'PUNCH') i get the error incorrect syntax near 'PTI-I20-13/16'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.

Comment: Because you also forgot commas (`,`) between each row, @ShayanK . The documentation has plenty of examples, including one on [Inserting multiple rows of data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-inserting-multiple-rows-of-data).

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotes to wrap the column names.

Try,

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory VALUES

('131-NJB572', 'BROOM')
,('PTI-I20', '9/16 IRONWORKERS')
,('PTI-I16', '13/16" PUNCH');
```

Comment: You were missing the commas